# POST Method in httr library with specific headers in R

Tags: json, r, http

I want to receive a **json string** as a response from a REST API URL.
It has 
**header as `Content-Type=application/json`.**
It should have a body with json format
eg-**`{"string1":"string2","string3":"string4"}`**

These are the details I am inputting when using POSTMAN. What is the correct Syntax for the above requirement.

I am trying the following syntax but it always throws an error:

```
POST(url = login,add_headers('Content-Type'='application/json'),body = c("string1"="string2","string3"="string4"),encode = c("json"),verbose())
```

Comment: Can you attach the error thrown?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
POST(url = login,add_headers('Content-Type'='application/json'),body = list(string1="string2",string3="string4"),encode = "json",verbose())
```

Comment: It should be a POST function with separate headers. The above mentioned will work when no headers are required with direct access to json file.